# Oracle Enterprise Manager - stats split by user (schema)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-enterprise-manager

Is there any way to split all the stats by user (schema) when looking at the Performance tab in the Oracle 11g Enterprise Manager?

[image: Enteprise Manager Performance tab (not my screenshot)]

or effectively some other tool to retrieve that information - e.g. a running chart of #active sessions for user (that's probably easy by probing the v$session or similar). Or a running chart of I/O Megabytes per Second broken by user/schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find what you're looking for by clicking the "Top Activity" link in the bottom right.  When you get to the Top Activity page, try changing the drop down menu on the right side from "Top Sessions" to "Top Clients." You can then click on an individual user session to get more details about that session.

Comment: Thanks. I see there "100%" and no label next to it. If I scroll the time axis I see some marginal "0.6%" or similar for the Enterprise Manager session and rest the same. http://imgur.com/yK6L2f4